# backspace and delete button does NOT delete characters in a textarea on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In my application , I have a text area in which a user is not able to delete the characters entered using backspace or using delete keys in IE9. This works on Chrome.

I have the following code

```
$('textarea').live('keydown', function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 9) {
            var currentIndex = getCaret($(this).get(0))
            selectText($(this), currentIndex);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

and Im using the **jQuery.highlighttextarea.js** which highlights the words on a pattern.
Im not sure whether  **jQuery.highlighttextarea.js** needs to be modified to handle backspace or delete .
Please suggest

I did use it like

I did use it like

```
if (e.which == 9) {
var currentIndex = getCaret($(this).get(0))
            selectText($(this), currentIndex);
            return false;
    }

if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46)  {
    return false;

}
```

However now backspace or delete don't work

Comment: Do not use `var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;`. jQuery normalizes the key code into `e.which` - just use that

Comment: ... and `live` is dead.

Comment: @undefined lol, nice one

Comment: live was deprected in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Use `on()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keycode 9 is `tab`. Check here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

You want `8` and `46`, so something like:

```
if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) return false;
```

Comment: Please see the original question comment

Answer (score 1):

Add this trigger to **jquery.highlighttextarea.js** :

```
'keydown.highlightTextarea' : $.proxy(function(e) {

                    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                    if (keyCode == 9) {
                        var currentIndex = getCaret($(e.target).get(0))
                        selectText($(e.target), currentIndex);
                        return false
                    } 
                    if (keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 46) {
                        this.highlight(true);
                    }
                    this.highlight(true);

                }, this),
```